# Twitter Turning off Basic Auth - is OAuth overkill for some tasks?

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

According to [Twitter docs, basic auth is being turned off this month](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Authentication).

I can see the benefit of OAuth when your service accepts third party user twitter login/id's, but for a simple twitter bot that simply post to a single bot twitter account, does OAuth seem like overkill?

In the case of the latter, what's the least resource-expendful PHP way to get OAuth to auth for the simple purpose of posting to twitter.

Comment: I'd certainly love to see fewer Twitter bots.

Comment: well, bots are indispensable for some convenience features like shopping deal twitters

Comment: @ina: I'm sure that's exactly why @BoltClock would like to see fewer twitter bots.

Comment: don't follow bots you're not interested in? ... set your timeline to private if you don't want bots to follow you? - solution for @BoltClock @Tomalak

Comment: @ina: and make it impossible for real people to read my tweets before following me? Sure...

Comment: @BoltClock have a bot relay your (public) tweets to public twitter portion of your blog/website. people would check out your website first before following anyway. once on your own serverside, you can even sanitize your tweets from RT's and @short-obscure-reply madness to include tweets that actually make sense! - metaedit out the crap from your regular stream

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you OAuth is an overkill and this is the wrong use case for OAuth. OAuth is designed to authorize third-party so its flow is complicated. However, Basic Auth is indeed insecure and there is not way you can revoke the access without changing password.

OAuth is not designed for bot, it requires user action. It's just too much trouble to simulate the whole flow in the server code. You can simply use examples here,

http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

Once you get the access token and token secret, save them in your bot. At posting time, simply include the token and sign your request.